# How to add a line break into a submit input

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a way to display the value of an 
`<input type="submit">`
on 2 lines, so potentially add a line break in it, but i tried multiple stuff such as :

- `<br>`
- `\r\n`
- `\n`
- `&#10;`

The result should be like this (On the right side of the picture) :

[image: the result]

Nothing works. Anyone got a clue on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```css
div.full {
  width:500px;
  background-color:grey;
}

div.left {
  float:left;
  width:60%
}

button {
  width:40%;
  text-align:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}

div.underline {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='full'>
  <div class='left'>
    there is a part of text
  </div>
  <button>J'essaie gratuitement
    <div class='underline'>30 jours</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

I just added some CSS to keep the size of the button.  and line breaks are not a very good practice. You'd better do it with css.

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your css:
A white-space property will allow to have input in multiple lines

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 150px;
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="J'essaie gratuitement 30 jours" />
```

Two other methods are

```
<button type="submit">Multiple line<br/>input</button>
```

and

using `&#13;&#10;` carriage return in between the input value as:

```
<input type="button" value="Multiple line&#13;&#10;input" style="text-align:center;">
```

The last method however doesn't work in IE10

Answer (score 11):

Use `button` instead of `input`:

```css
.right-aligned {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="right-aligned">Text <br /> broken </button>
```

Buttons can accept a variety of other tags inside, such as `<br />`, `<span>`.

Then, you can style it with CSS however you wish (see the CSS class and rules in the code snippet).

Answer (score 3):

I think you try this in HTML:

Just as example help for you:

```html
<input type="button" value="Really&#x00A;Tall&#x00A; Button">
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use a standard `<a>` or `<span>` tag.

```js
var submits = document.getElementsByClassName('submit');

for (var i = 0; i < submits.length; i++) {
  submits[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('submit!');
      document.getElementById('form_to_submit').submit();
    });
  }
```

```css
.submit {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" title="Clickie" class="submit">J'essaie gratuitement<br>30 jours</a></p>

<p><span class="submit">J'essaie gratuitement<br>30 jours</span></p>
```